# Raise tensor product to float power in qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, circuit-construction, linear-algebra

I am trying to implement the gate

$(X \otimes X)^\alpha$

where $X$ is the standard Pauli-X gate, $\otimes$ is the tensor product and $\alpha$ is a real number. Is there a way to implement this in a qiskit circuit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qiskit's [`Gate.power()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.Gate.power.html) method accepts `float` exponent. So, you can implement it as follows:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import PauliGate

alpha = 2.73
xxp_gate = PauliGate('XX').power(alpha)
circ.append(xxp_gate, [0, 1])
```

The result:

[image]

Internally, `power()` method diagonalizes the unitary, raises the diagonal entries to the specified power, then constructs the resulting gate.