# Raising Pauli Gate to power gives TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'complex' and 'ParameterVectorElement'

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit

I am trying to implement a parameterised circuit in qiskit. Part of the circuit includes the operation

$(X \otimes X)^\alpha$

where $X$ is the standard Pauli-X gate, $\otimes$ is the tensor product, and $\alpha$ is any real number. Someone was so kind to help me implement this operation in another question: [Raise tensor product to float power in qiskit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26593/raise-tensor-product-to-float-power-in-qiskit) and when I run it the way it was suggested, it works fine. However, when I paste it into a class, I get an error. This is my implementation:

```
class QuantumCircuit:
    
    def __init__(self, backend, shots=100):
        
        self._q = qiskit.QuantumRegister(3, 'q')
        self._c = qiskit.ClassicalRegister(1, 'c')
        self._circuit = qiskit.QuantumCircuit(self._q, self._c)
        
        self.inp = qiskit.circuit.ParameterVector('inp', 2)  
        self.param = qiskit.circuit.ParameterVector('param', 2)  
        
        #encoding
        self.phase_gate = Ph(self.inp[0], [0])
        self._circuit.append(self.phase_gate, [0])
        self._circuit.rx(self.inp[0], 0)
        
        self.phase_gate = Ph(self.inp[1], [0])
        self._circuit.append(self.phase_gate, [1])
        self._circuit.rx(self.inp[1], 1)

        for param in self.param:
            xx10 = PauliGate('XX').power(self.param[0])
            xx11 = PauliGate('XX').power(self.param[1])
            self._circuit.append(xx10, [0, 2])
            self._circuit.append(xx11, [1, 2])
            
            yy10 = PauliGate('YY').power(self.param[2])
            yy11 = PauliGate('YY').power(self.param[3])
            self._circuit.append(yy10, [0, 2])
            self._circuit.append(yy11, [1, 2])
            
            zz10 = PauliGate('ZZ').power(self.param[4])
            zz11 = PauliGate('ZZ').power(self.param[5])
            self._circuit.append(zz10, [0, 2])
            self._circuit.append(zz11, [1, 2])
            
        self._circuit.measure(2, 0)
        
        self.backend = backend
        self.shots = shots
        
    def run(self, inp, theta):
        qc = transpile(self._circuit, self.backend)
        
        #parameter assignment
        bind_dict = {}
        j = 0
        k = 0
        for key in qc.parameters:
            if j <= 1: #this is the number of inputs, at the moment we have two inputs
                bind_dict[key] = inp[j]
                j+=1
            else:                
                bind_dict[key] = theta[k]
                k+=1

        qc.assign_parameters(bind_dict, inplace=True)
        
        #run the circuit
        job = execute(qc, self.backend, shots=self.shots)
        result = job.result()
        c = result.get_counts()
        
        states = np.array(list(c.keys())).astype(float)
        counts = np.array(list(c.values())).astype(int)
        
        dist = counts/self.shots
        E = np.array([np.sum(states * dist)])
        
        return E
```

The error that I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [48] in <cell line: 2>
    circ = QuantumCircuit(backend, shots=10)
  Input In [47] in __init__
    xx10 = PauliGate('XX').power(self.param[0])
  File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/circuit/gate.py:85 in power
    decomposition_power.append(pow(element, exponent))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'complex' and 'ParameterVectorElement'

Use %tb to get the full traceback.
```

For information, the lists of parameters that I used are

```
inp = array([0.50002703, 0.56683592])
theta = array([2.37624305, 5.00052773, 1.60817906, 1.01813369, 1.36693303,
       2.58211921])
```

Any ideas how to circumvent this problem?

Comment: It looks like the exponent of the PauliGate.power() has to be a value (float) and cannot be a ParameterExpression like when using a rx gate (qc.rx(param[0], [0])) 
Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use [`Gate.power()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.Gate.power.html) because it does not accept `qiskit.circuit.Parameter`. You can, however, implement $(X \otimes X)^\alpha$ using the parameterized gate [$R_{xx}(\theta)$](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.RXXGate.html)

$$R_{xx}(\theta)=\exp(-i\frac{\theta}{2}X \otimes X)$$

We have, $R_{xx}(\pi)=iX \otimes X$.

So, $(X \otimes X)^\alpha$ is equivalent to $R_{xx}(\pi\alpha)$ *up to a global phase*.

Hence, instead of:

```
xx10 = PauliGate('XX').power(self.param[0])
self._circuit.append(xx10, [0, 2])
```

which causes the error, you can write:

```
self._circuit.rxx(np.pi * self.param[0], 0, 2)
```

Or, if you don't want to have a global phase difference:

```
self._circuit.rxx(np.pi * self.param[0], 0, 2)
self._circuit.x(0)
self._circuit.u(np.pi, np.pi * self.param[0] / 2, np.pi + np.pi * self.param[0] / 2, 0)
```

Similarly, you can use [$R_{yy}$](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.RYYGate.html) and [$R_{zz}$](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.RZZGate.html) to implement $(Y \otimes Y)^\alpha$ and $(Z \otimes Z)^\alpha$ respectively using the fact that,

$R_{yy}(\pi)=iY \otimes Y$, and $R_{zz}(\pi)=-Z \otimes Z$

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Qiskit allows raising gates to real powers, but complains when using `ParameterVector` elements as exponents. Why don't you use the fact that $X = HZH$, so computing $X^{\alpha}$ is same as $HZ^{\alpha}H$. Finding $Z^{\alpha}$ is trivial because the exponent is applied to the diagonal elements of $Z^{\alpha} = \begin{pmatrix}
1& 0\\
0 & (-1)^{\alpha}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
1& 0\\
0 & e^{i\pi\alpha}
\end{pmatrix}$, which is a `PhaseGate`. So you can reduce $X^{\alpha}$ to $HP(\alpha\pi)H$.